# Reinstall vscode snap package to new "code" snap

Tags: visual-studio-code

I received a warning on snap that the `vscode` will no longer be updated by Snapcrafters because the official visual studio code team released the official snap package which is the `code` and advised me to do

- `snap remove vscode`
- `sudo snap install code --classic`

During the installation of `code` I got an error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "code" (6) from channel "stable" (stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR)
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: This has been resolved. (Ubuntu 18.04)